# Wordpress Multisite with Different Domains

Tags: wordpress, multisite

The available tutorials state that we can have a network of subdomains or directories.

Is it possible to have one single installation that supports many differents domains:

domain-1.com => wordpress site 1
other-domain.com => wordpress site n

Comment: Do you mean the same WP installation (i.e. code base and database) would be accessed through two separate domains?

Comment: @MacPrawn please check this https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_2:_Allow_Multisite but for differente domains instead of folders or subdomains.

Comment: @philipp why can you orientae me, I am in the exploration phase of the most suitable solution, I have a bunch of sites that are quite similar each one target one specific city, I want to run them with one wordpress installation, if I want to update it, I will update one installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - don't know about "evil", but the idea of all my websites using the same database and code base never pleased me... First because of performance, second because it's easier to "see" other site's data, at least in theory...

Anyway, to answer your question, I don't believe WP will allow you to use completely different domains, no. You could use rewrites, but those won't be seamless, i.e. your visitors will actually be redirected to the final domain.